# blazor , task.delay, css manipulation

Tags: c#, css, async-await, blazor

i would like to create a gradient effect in blazor  like https://gradienta.io/editor moving the angle slider.
I thought to do it by using the task.delay function, but only  1 and 3 are shown , what i am i missing here that 2 is not shown.
Eventually i want to put it in a loop , to set the gradient in motion.

```
<div class="box-size" style=@myStyle>
       @content
    </div>
}

@code {
    public string myStyle = "";
    public string content = "";

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
                
        myStyle = "background-image: linear-gradient(80deg, #FF0055 0%, #000066 100%)";
        content = "1";
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        myStyle = "background-image: linear-gradient(160deg, #FF0044 0%, #000066 100%)";
        content = "2";
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        myStyle = "background-image: linear-gradient(240deg, #FF0011 0%, #000066 100%)";
        content = "3";
       

    }
```

Comment: Might need to leverage `StateHasChanged`, but is there a reason you aren't using CSS `@keyframes`?

Comment: Just wanted to experiment, with blazor and async task. To see if it is possible tot animatie a gradiënt css.

Comment: OnInitalized is a very strange place to put something that active.  Try a different event, or run your code in an event handler.  Also, if you are animating, I hope you're using WASM.   If you're using a server, then it's likely to work great at home, and then be very rough due to ping issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is addressed at MS Docs: [An asynchronous handler involves multiple asynchronous phases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/rendering?view=aspnetcore-5.0#an-asynchronous-handler-involves-multiple-asynchronous-phases)

TLDR: [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=net-5.0) receivers can only observe their final completion, not intermediate asynchronous states. [`ComponentBase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.componentbase?view=aspnetcore-5.0) will automatically trigger re-rendering when the task is first returned and when it finally completes. You therefore have to manually call [`StateHasChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.componentbase.statehaschanged?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to trigger re-rendering at those intermediate points.

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{                
    myStyle = "background-image: linear-gradient(80deg, #FF0055 0%, #000066 100%)";
    content = "1";
    // first return, renders here automatically

    await Task.Delay(5000);
    myStyle = "background-image: linear-gradient(160deg, #FF0044 0%, #000066 100%)";
    content = "2";
    // intermediate point, manual invocation required
    StateHasChanged();

    await Task.Delay(5000);
    myStyle = "background-image: linear-gradient(240deg, #FF0011 0%, #000066 100%)";
    content = "3";  
    // completion, renders here automatically
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Blazor will automatically call StateHasChanged() at the first `await` in your method (which will render and show step1).

It will then automatically call StateHasChanged() again at the end of your method - which will render step 3.

To see step 2 you would need an extra StateHasChanged() call in the middle

```cs
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
                
        myStyle = "background-image: linear-gradient(80deg, #FF0055 0%, #000066 100%)";
        content = "1";
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        myStyle = "background-image: linear-gradient(160deg, #FF0044 0%, #000066 100%)";
        content = "2";
        StateHasChanged(); // This will render Step 2
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        myStyle = "background-image: linear-gradient(240deg, #FF0011 0%, #000066 100%)";
        content = "3";      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> create a gradient effect in blazor like https://gradienta.io/editor moving the angle slider

Gradiant angle is not a supported animation type.  The other answers here will NOT animate the angle.

To animate the angle:
(I would only do this in WASM)

`AnimatedBackground.razor`

```
<div class="css-selector" style="width:200px;height:200px;">
</div>
<style>
    :root {
        --angle: @($"{Angle}deg");
    }
</style>
```

`AnimatedBackground.razor.cs`

```
public partial class AnimatedBackground: IDisposable
{
    [Inject]
    private IAnimationTickService TickService { get; set; }

    private double Angle { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        TickService.TimerSyncEvent += AnimationTickService_OnTick;
    }

    private void AnimationTickService_OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const double duration = 20;
        const double fps = AnimationTickService.FPS;
        const double incAmount = (360/fps)/duration;
        Angle += incAmount;
        Angle %= 360;
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        TickService.TimerSyncEvent -= AnimationTickService_OnTick;
    }
}
```

`AnimatedBackground.razor.css`

```
.css-selector {
    background: linear-gradient(var(--angle), #FF0055 0%, #000066 100%);
    background-size: 600% 600%;
}
```

`AnimationTickService.cs`

```
public class AnimationTickService : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Timer timer;
    public const double FPS = 25;
    public AnimationTickService()
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000.0 / FPS;
        timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Start();
    }

    public event EventHandler TimerSyncEvent;
    
    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        => TimerSyncEvent?.Invoke(sender, e);
    
    public void Dispose()
    {
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

`Program.cs`

```
   builder.Services.AddScoped< AnimationTickService>();
```

Try to avoid doing this, use a pure css approach. You can animate the `background-postion` and the color stops to get a similar result with an `infinate` animation.

[Pure CSS Similar effect](https://codepen.io/brian-parker-the-selector/pen/wvJRGKM)

Answer (score 0):

I think a MUCH better option for animating colors (and shapes) would be to use inline svg.

SVG have built-in animation capabilities.